# How to understand the command awk '{for(x=1;$x;++x)print $x}'?

Tags: awk

I know this command

```
awk '{for(x=1;$x;++x)print $x}'
```

will print out all columns in a line.

wouldn't this `++x`  change `x` to 2, and thus print `$2` first?
As I understood based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812990/incrementing-in-c-when-to-use-x-or-x

And what does the `$x` do in `for(x=1;$x;++x)` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. The `for(i=0;i<10;i++)` is a classic programming construct (see [Traditional for loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#Traditional_for_loops)) that is present in many languages. It can be broken down to:

```
start-expression; end-condition; end-of-iteration-expression
```

In other words, what I wrote above means "initialize i to 0 and, while i is less than 10, do something and *then* increment i by 1. Yes the syntax is confusing but that's just the way it is. The `end-of-iteration-expression` (`++x` in this case) is executed once at the end of each loop. It is equivalent to writing:

```
while(i<10){print i; ++i}
```

As for the `$x`, I believe that just checks that a field of that number exists and that its contents do not evaluate to false (as explained in Mathias's [answer below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149242/22222)). `$N` will return true if the field number N exists and is not a type of `false`. For example:

```
$ echo "a b c d" | awk '($4){print "yes"}'
yes
$ echo "a b c d" | awk '($14){print "yes"}' ## prints nothing, no $14
$ echo "a b c 0" | awk '($4){print "yes"}' ## prints nothing, $4 is 0
```

As you can see above, the first command prints `yes` because there is a `$4`. Since there is no `$14`, the second prints nothing. So, to get back to your original example:

```
awk '{for(x=1;$x;x++)print $x}' 
          ___ __ ___
           |   |  |
           |   |  |-----> increment x by 1 at the end of each loop.
           |   |--------> run the loop as long as there is a field number x
           |------------> initialize x to 1
```

Comment: cool stuff, good explanation :)

Comment: But why if I write ` echo 'a b c d e' | awk '{for(x=1;$5;++x)print NR,$x}'` I have an infinite loop? With  echo 'a b c d ' | awk '{for(x=1;$5;++x)print NR,$x}' it prints nothing as expected.

Comment: @Hastur because there will _always_ be a `$5`. So, every time the loop runs, it checks whether `$5` exists. Because it does, the loop will be executed. This will go on until there is no `$5` which will never happen because your input has at least 5 fields. The second prints nothing because the condition fails immediately: there is no $5.

Comment: The first part is not a _condition_. It's more like `start-expression; end-condition; end-of-iteration-expression` (note that the `end-of-iteration-expression` doesn't have to be an increment).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas fair point, answer edited. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I understood it is checked before, and once it is inside the `for loop` it will never exit to read the next line, incrementing always the field printed as it's possible to see from `awk '{for(x=1;1;++x)print NR, NF, x, $x}'`

Comment: You should add `i=0;` before `while(i<10){print i; ++i}`, otherwise it's not equivalent and just UB.

Comment: @gurka that's just pseudocode really. I just used it as an example of a conditional loop.

Answer (score 6):

Since terdon provided a comprehensive answer I just want to add that if any column evaluates to false, the for statement ends the loop, as you can see in this example:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 0 6|awk '{for(x=1;$x;++x)print $x}' 
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: A more correct awk program would be `{for(x=1;$x"";++x)print $x}`. This works because it fixes the type of the test expression as a *string*, rather than a *numeric string*, and a string is false only if it is empty. With the default `FS`, an empty field is possible only at the end of the fields.

Comment: @rici, it means your program wouldn't stop when it meets 0 in a line, right?

Comment: @rici, I've tested it, it avoid the 0 problem. It's quite important in this issue, I think you really should write a supplement answer for this point. Great point.

Answer (score 3):

1. `++x` and `x++` are functionally equivalent when used stand-alone. 
   As discussed in the Stack Overflow question that you referenced,

   - There may be *performance* (i.e., timing) differences.
   - The results of `something = ++x;`
     and `something = x++;` are different –
     but your example isn’t doing that.

   So, as far as the incrementing of `x` is concerned,
   your example is equivalent to

   ```
   awk '{for(x=1;$x;x++) print $x}'
   ```
2. The standalone `$x` is equivalent to `$x != ""`,
   so the loop will iterate until it encounters a blank field. 
   This is a lazy shortcut for `x <= NF`,
   where `NF` is the number of fields in the current record (line). 
   For the purposes of your example, this is harmless, AFAICT. 
   But, if you specify a non-default field separator,

   ```
   awk -F, '{for(x=1;$x;++x) print $x}'
   ```

   this will try to do the same as your example, but splitting lines at commas. 
   If you type `a   b`, it will output `a   b`. 
   If you type `a,b`, it will print `a` and `b` on separate lines. 
   But if you input `a,,b`, it will output `a` and then stop, because `$2` is null.

Comment: `$x` is not equivalent to `$x != ""` because values like 0, +0, " 0", -0e12 also all evaluate to false.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: It's more complicated than that. "0" only evaluates to false if it's considered a numeric string. `awk 'BEGIN {a="0";if(a)print a" is true";else print a" is false"'}`. Contrast the numeric string case: `awk -v a=0 'BEGIN {if(a)print a" is true";else print a" is false"'}` or `awk 'BEGIN {a=ARGV[1];if(a)print a" is true";else print a" is false"'} 0`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas (of course, in the context of G-Man's incorrect assertion, your statement is correct because a field is a numeric string context.)